# Downloads not showing on iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, itunesconnect-analytics

I released an update for my app yesterday that hasn't been updated in over a year. I know for a fact that a few of my friends (who did not and never did have the previous version installed) installed my app throughout the day yesterday. But, iTunes connect is showing "0" units for April 4 (yesterday) and the past week for that matter.

I'm asking because I remember the last time I released this app the number of downloads ( or units: this is the same thing right?) showed up accurately the next morning. It also showed the correct units number for another app I recently released. Is there some sort of delay that's new? I just want to make sure nothing is set up incorrectly. I'm also using admob if that matters, and impressions/clicks are showing up fine there.

Thanks![image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to wait one day or two to see the results. There is a delay.

Answer (score 1):

You can find static on [iTunesConnect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com) portal 
Select sales & Trends.